# Google Document AI Warehouse - getdocument issue

Tags: java, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to getDocument using Document AI Warehouse Java API's. I am getting the below error:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:92)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:41)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:84)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1127)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1286)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1055)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:807)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:568)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:538)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:541)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:489)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:453)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:486)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:567)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:71)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:735)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:716)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.contentwarehouse.v1.DocumentServiceClient.getDocument(DocumentServiceClient.java:400)
```

What am i missing.

I have used the java sample mentioned in this link:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/content-warehouse/src/main/java/contentwarehouse/v1/GetDocument.java
kindly help to find the issue.